# Approval History Related List in Visualforce Email Template

Tags: visualforce, email-template, approval-process

Am wondering how to get usable info in the approval hisotry I can add to my visualforce email template.
I have the below (UPDATED):

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Lead Final Approval" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Lead">

<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
//lots of Lead fields    
<table border="0" >

<apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.ProcessSteps}">
    <tr>

        <td>Step Status: {!cx.StepStatus}</td>
        <td>Completed:{!cx.ProcessInstance.CompletedDate}</td>
        <td>Instance Status:{!cx.ProcessInstance.Status}</td>
        <td>Time:{!cx.ProcessInstance.ElapsedTimeInHours}</td>
        <td>Actor Id: {!cx.ActorId}</td>


    </tr>


  </apex:repeat>                 
</table>

    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>

    </messaging:emailTemplate>
```

It gets me stuff of partial value, for example:

> Step Status: Approved Completed:Thu Mar 05 14:56:20 GMT 2015  Instance Status:Approved    Time:0.003611111111111111   Actor Id: 005U0000000OnR8IAK
>   Step Status: Started    Completed:Thu Mar 05 14:56:20 GMT 2015  Instance Status:Approved    Time:0.003611111111111111   Actor Id: 005U0000000OnR8IAK    Comments:
>   Step Status: Approved   Completed:Thu Mar 05 14:56:20 GMT 2015  Instance Status:Approved    Time:0.003611111111111111   Actor Id: 005U0000000OnR8IAK
>   Step Status: Approved   Completed:Thu Mar 05 14:56:20 GMT 2015  Instance Status:Approved    Time:0.003611111111111111   Actor Id: 005U0000000OnR8IAK

Thus I can get related info from ProcessSteps to the ProcessInstance sometimes via

```
<td>Completed:{!cx.ProcessInstance.CompletedDate}</td>
```

but I want to get for example:
Actor: {!cx.ActorId.User.Firstname}

Comment: Were you able to find the answer for bringing the name from the Actor ID?
If yes, Could you please share with us? Thanks,
Mounika

Answer (score 1):

Please use following so that you will get name:

```
Actor: {!cx.Actor.name}
```

I hope this will solve your issue

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. I got actor name fine. What I don't have is the name of the step in the approval process.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your query correctly. There are many approval process related objects which you can query for your usage.

> ProcessDefinition - Represents the definition of a single approval
>   process.
>
> ProcessInstance - Represents an instance of a single, end-to-end
>   approval process. Use this and the node, step, and workitem process
>   instance objects to create approval history reports.
>
> ProcessInstanceHistory - This read-only object shows all steps and
>   pending approval requests associated with an approval process
>   (ProcessInstance).
>
> ProcessInstanceStep - Represents one work item in an approval process
>   (ProcessInstance).
>
> ProcessInstanceNode - Represents a step in an instance of an approval
>   process.

Comment: In my example I am using ProcessSteps as the related to as shown. It gives me Actor ID, which is the who, but how do I turn that into the person's name, for exmaple?

Comment: Updated code example in post

Comment: OK, i am getting more - almost all of the related fields except the Step Name - stepnode name but how to relate. Will probably find it soon...

Comment: what is the correct version of  <td>Step: {!cx.ProcessInstance.ProcessInstanceNode.name}</td> to get the Approval Step's name?

Comment: What is relatedToType attribute in your template ? With the email templates, you need to use the sObject which the email template will be related to.  If you have an email template that you're going to use with your "ProcessInstance" custom object, your email template should be related to ProcessInstance

Comment: You use "RelatedTo" instead of the specific object name.  Try this {!RelatedTo.ProcessInstance.name} if your relatedToType = ProcessInstanceNode

Comment: Lead is my template b/c I want the lead fields and then the related approval history : <messaging:emailTemplate subject="Lead Final Approval" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Lead">

Comment: ProcessInstance is not a custom object

Comment: <td>Step Name: {!cx}</td> will give me the idea of the step in the approval process....  but the name, the name? wtf.

Comment: How odd no one knows how to do this.